# Apache RewriteRule redirect except for 1 path and 2 IPs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hope I can explain this well enough!

I have some RewriteRules for a site under Apache that I am using to redirect users to the same pages on a different server. There are two exceptions - I need to let through 2 IP addresses to access the original server, and I don't want the rules to apply to a particular path. Here is my current ruleset:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^10\.10\.10\.1(0|1)$
RewriteRule ^page/old/url/1$ http://www.site.com/new/url/1 [R=301,L]

# If the user is trying to get to /admin, let it past by skipping the next rewriterule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(|.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=1]

# Catch-all to send any "un-mapped" pages to the homepage
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^10\.10\.10\.1(0|1)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.site.com/homepage [R=301,L]

# Other rules follow, but no redirections
```

So, I want the htaccess to redirect all users except for 2 IP addresses to the new site location. I want to ensure though, that *anyone* can access **/admin**. There is then a catch-all rule to pick up any pages that haven't been specifically redirected.

It seems either the REQUEST_URI line isn't matching, or the skip rule isn't working. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem simpler to catch the conditions you don't want rewriting first, that way you don't need to worry about them in your other rules.

Something like this:

```
#Don't rewrite known IPs or path /admin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^10\.10\.10\.1(0|1)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin($|\/|\/.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Redirection rules
RewriteRule ^page/old/url/1/?$ http://www.site.com/new/url/1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/old/url/2/?$ http://www.site.com/new/url/2 [R=301,NC,L]
# Catch all
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```